# Change webmaster email address on 500

Tags: apache-2.4

When a user gets a 500 error from an Apache server under my control, it tells them to contact the webmaster, root@localhost . Is there a way to change this email address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ServerAdmin directive in your httpd.conf file.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveradmin for more information.